# How to change font size of QwtLegend?

Tags: qwt

I want to change the font size of my QwtLegend.

I tried

```
QFont label_font("Helvetica");
label_font.setPointSize(20);

QwtLegend *legend = new QwtLegend();
legend->setFont(label_font);
plot->insertLegend(legend, QwtPlot::TopLegend, 1.0);
```

and

```
QFont label_font("Helvetica");
label_font.setPointSize(20);

QwtLegend *legend = new QwtLegend();
plot->insertLegend(legend, QwtPlot::TopLegend, 1.0);
plot->legend()->setFont(label_font);
```

But both ways do not work. What is wrong here? How can I change the font size of QwtLegend items?

Comment: Better use Qwt support channels - moderators of this forum seem to dislike being it used.

Comment: Why should they dislike?

Comment: Your code is 100% correct ( both implementations ) and works when being used f.e in one of the Qwt examples. Why giving you this simple piece of information has been removed by the admins - no idea. But in general the competence concerning Qwt questions is not very high here.

Comment: Thanks, Uwe. I had another mistake in my code. You are right, both ways work very well.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the font is taken from the legend's parent. I wrote the font into the plot's stylesheet and it worked.

```
myPlot = new QwtPlot(parent);
myPlot->setStyleSheet("background-color:black; color:yellow; 
                       border-radius: 0px; font: 8pt \"Deja Vu\";");

QwtLegend *thelegend =new QwtLegend(myPlot);
myPlot->insertLegend(thelegend, QwtPlot::BottomLegend, 0.0);
```